# Automatically increase id, in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

This is some of my code, first three events are already defined in system, but when user wants to create another event, `Event ID` should be `++1`. I could not define `Event ID`. Which way should I use?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Events.Models 
{
    public interface IRepository 
    {
        IEnumerable<Event> Events { get; }
        void AddEvent(Event newEvent);
    }

    public class MemoryRepository : IRepository 
    {
        private List<Event> events= new List<Event> 
        {
            new Event { id = 1, Name = "Event A", DOB = System.DateTime.Now, Duration = 60 },
            new Event { id = 2, Name = "Event B", DOB = System.DateTime.Now, Duration = 60 },
            new Event { id = 3, Name = "Event C", DOB = System.DateTime.Now, Duration = 60 },
        };

        public IEnumerable<Event> Events=> events;

        public void AddEvent(Event newEvent) 
        {
            events.Add(newEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to get last id of event list and increment one in it

Comment: What should happen when event is added after one of the events in the middle was removed ?

Comment: should be -1 but I could not get last id

Comment: you can create a method inside your repo class that looks like this :  `int IncreaseId(int id) {return id +1;}`

Answer (score 1):

The List() data type has a built in ID parameter.

Therefore, if you initialize a list of Event without an ID parameter, you can still access them by ID using this sort of code:

```
public Event GetEvent(int id) {
    if (events.Count > id)
        return events[id];
}
```